# Approximate value of hyperbolic tangent in certain case

Tags: taylor-expansion, physics, approximation, hyperbolic-functions, electromagnetism

I am reading [Thé Nature of Magnetism](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/_/EwUTRAAACAAJ?hl=en). While reading, I came across a particular approximation of hyperbolic tangent

- while in first case $T>T_c$ , it is just Taylor series,
- in case $T < T_c$ ( where an additional term is added to the argument of the hyperbolic tangent) , the approximation is not clear for me.

Snapshot of Pages

> [image]

Any hints? Please
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: For more context see https://archive.org/details/TheNatureOfMagnetismKaganov/page/n76/mode/2up?view=theater